# A concentration inequality with random normal distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

Given a constant $C >0$ and $X \sim {\cal N}(\vec{\mu}, \Sigma_{d \times d})$ then do we have a good upperbound on the deviation probability, $\mathbb{P} [ \Vert X \Vert \geq C ]$ ?

Assume $\Sigma$ is a diagonal or even isotropic if that makes it tractable.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what kind of upper bound you are looking for, and what regime of $C$? For instance, if $\Sigma=I$, then $\|X\|-\sqrt{d}$ is subexponential, so concentrates strongly around $0$. If $C\leq \sqrt{d}$, this implies the probability is basically $1$. So are you asking about $C>\sqrt{d}$? In general, I think this kind of thing is covered in Vershynin's recent book, though I haven't looked at it in a while...

Comment: I did try searching Vershynin's book but I cant locate anything specific. I am typically thinking of $C < \sqrt{d}$. I would like to get an upperbound as a function of $C$ and $d$ particularly in this regime. Also did you have a typo : If $\Vert X \Vert - \sqrt{d}$ concentrates around $0$ and say $C = \sqrt{d}/2$, then the probability I am looking at is almost $0$, right?

Comment: Suppose norm is euclidian. The norm $||X||$ is then a chi-squared distribution, so you can bound it using the chi-squared CDF.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X':=X-\mu$. For $C'\equiv C-\|\mu\|_2>0$, there exists a constant $M>0$ s.t.
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(\|X\|_2>C)&\le\mathsf{P}(\|X'\|_2>C')\overset{(1)}{\le} 2\exp\left(-\frac{C'^2}{2\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma)}\right).
\end{align}

---

*Proof of $(1)$*. Let $Q\Lambda Q^{\top}$ be the eigendecomposition of $\Sigma$. Then $\|X'\|_2\overset{d}{=}\|\Lambda^{1/2} Y\|_2$, where $Y\sim N(0,I_d)$, and for $y\ge 0$ and $s>0$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(\|\Lambda^{1/2} Y\|_2>y)&\le \mathsf{P}(\|\Lambda^{1/2}Y\|_1>y)\le e^{-sy}\prod_{i=1}^d\mathsf{E}e^{s\sqrt{\lambda_i}|Y_i|} \\
&\le 2e^{\frac{s^2}{2}\sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i-sy},
\end{align}
where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d$ are the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$. Optimizing over $s$, one gets
$$
\mathsf{P}(\|\Lambda^{1/2} Y\|_2>y)\le 2e^{-\frac{y^2}{2\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i}}=2e^{-\frac{y^2}{2\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma)}} \tag*{$\square$}
$$

Comment: Well. How do I get this M? :D I really need all the constants here! What are you using here to get the second inequality?

Comment: The second inequality comes from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0047259X86900850) (Lemma 4, p. 307).

Comment: WoW! This isnt something standard that is in textbooks yet!

Comment: [Apparently](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351523/gaussian-concentration-inequality/351639#351639), the referenced inequality is incorrect. So I replaced it with the second one.

Comment: WOW! This is so cool! I thought I was asking a trivial question :D