# Tail of the norm of a Gaussian vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, normed-spaces, gaussian

Let $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2I)$ where $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\sigma^2\in\mathbb{R}$. From subgaussian norm concentration, we know that the norm $\|X-\mu\|_2$ concentrates around $\sigma\sqrt{n}$. Is there any way to get a tail bound for the norm? Something of the form:
$$\mathbb{P}(\|X - \mu\|_2 > t) \le C\exp(-cf(t, \sigma, n)).$$

I am looking for the function $f(t, \sigma, n)$. Any hints or directions to work in would help. Thanks!

Comment: My calculations show that $f(t, \sigma, n)=t^2/\sigma^2$ (ignoring lower order terms). Could someone please confirm this? I'm finding it hard to believe that $n$ turns out to be not important in the tail!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527257/a-concentration-inequality-with-random-normal-distributions

Comment: The link above gives:
$$
\mathsf{P}(\|X-\mu\|_2>t)\le 2\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2n\sigma^2}\right).
$$